# Did I find a compiler bug in java 9?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, java-9

I'm getting a compile error in Eclipse on line 11.

Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Object>` to `List<JavaCompilerBug.Foo>`

I believe this code should compile and I've created a short example that demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class JavaCompilerBug {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> vals = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    List<Foo> foos = map(vals, s -> Foo.with(last(vals)));
  }

  public static class Foo {
    public static Foo with(String value) {
      return new Foo();
    }

    public static Foo with(Foo value) {
      return new Foo();
    }
  }

  public static <A, B> List<B> map(List<A> input, Function<A, B> function) {
    List<B> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (A element : input) {
      ret.add(function.apply(element));
    }
    return ret;
  }

  public static <T> T last(List<T> c) {
    return c.get(c.size() - 1);
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems to be an inference bug (happens with eclipse). Using explicit type witnesses with either `map` or `last` solve the problem. Compiles fine with `javac` regardless.

Comment: Compiles fine with javac from 9.0.4 and 10 both.

Comment: This must be a problem with eclipse then if it works with javac.

Comment: I keep running into type inference failures with Eclipse (almost to the point where a canonical would be justified). I'm too lazy too submit bug reports though, so feel free to self-answer the question with a link to the bug report you're making.

Comment: When attempting to find bugs in the Java compiler, make sure that you actually use the Java compiler ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is actually with Eclipse and not the Java compiler.  This issue has been filed with Eclipse here:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532860

Comment: The problem has already been fixed in Eclipse via https://bugs.eclipse.org/515600 (fix available in Photon builds since 4.8 M4).